# Linear regression on a large dataset

Tags: least-squares, online-algorithms

I want to run linear regression on a dataset who is too large to be loaded into memory. I intend to simply calculate

$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_ix_i^T\right)^{-1} \cdot \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i\right)$$
but one issue is that my input data is all different scales. If the scale is sufficiently small, it's OK as I can simply scale the dataset to lie in $[-1, 1]$ all at once, using.

```
X = 2 * (X-X.min())/(X.max()-X.min()) - 1
```

But how can I scale it if I'm doing it iteratively? We won't know the `max` and `min` apriori.

Comment: If you've got *that much* data do you really need to use all of it if you're just doing simple linear regression? Try some simple random samples of $10^1$,$10^2$, $10^3$, $10^4$ to see if increasing the sample size really matters. There is diminishing returns to the improvement of the standard errors of your parameters.

Comment: Why do you need to scale the data? Linear regression is affine equivariant, so you'll get equivalent results whether you scale or not.

Comment: What software are you using? Some programs are a lot better at handling large data sets than others or have suitable functions to do it bit by bit.

Comment: Too large to be loaded into memory, needs to be processed streaming: fine. But that doesn't mean you can only read it *once*. You can make one pass computing summary statistics like min, max, and mean, and a second pass where you have those numbers available.

Answer (score 7):

There are specialized algorithms that allow estimating a least squares problem iteratively, so you don't have to have the entire dataset in memory, but can update your solution by iterating over the data. Take a look at [LSQR](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4075853/51074) or [LSMR](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1664128/51074), depending on the properties of your design matrix $X$.